# Sum when field does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following table:

```
create table #tbl
(
  [type] varchar(20),
  [qty] int
)


insert into #tbl values ('Type A', 10)
insert into #tbl values ('Type A', 15)
insert into #tbl values ('Type B', 5)
insert into #tbl values ('Type B', 8)
```

Now I want to display the total qty of each individual 'type':

```
select
 isnull([type], 'Other') as [type],
 sum(case 
  when [type] = 'Type A' then qty
  when [type] = 'Type B' then qty
  when [type] = 'Type C' then qty 
  else 0
 end) as [total]
from #tbl
where [type] in ('Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C')
group by [type]
```

It correctly sums up each 'type'. Here's the result:

```
type    total
--------------
Type A     25
Type B     13
```

But I want Type C to be included in the result as well (with a total qty of 0).

```
type    total
--------------
Type A     25
Type B     13
Type C      0
```

How can I accomplish that?
I'm using MS SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have `Type C` in the table so there is nothing to return.  One way you could this is to create a derived table with all of the values that you want include and then LEFT JOIN your table:

```
select d.type,
  sum(coalesce(t.qty, 0)) Total
from
(
  select 'Type A' type union all
  select 'Type B' type union all
  select 'Type C' type 
) d
left join tbl t
  on d.type = t.type
group by d.type;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2893/7)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a table containing the list of types you want to report and do a left join on that. Something like the following:

```
create table #tbl
(
  [type] varchar(20),
  [qty] int
);

insert into #tbl values ('Type A', 10)
insert into #tbl values ('Type A', 15)
insert into #tbl values ('Type B', 5)
insert into #tbl values ('Type B', 8)

create table #types ( [type] varchar(20) );

insert into #types values ('Type A' );
insert into #types values ('Type B' );
insert into #types values ('Type C' );

select  t.[type], [Total] = IsNull(t.[total], 0)
from    (   select  [type] = IsNull(t.[Type], 'Other')
            ,       [total] = sum(tbl.[qty])
            from    #types                      t
            left
            join    #tbl                        tbl     ON  tbl.[type] = t.type
            group
            by      t.[type]
        ) as t
;
```

The sub-query is necessary to convert the NULL sums to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can get the result by applying both the UNPIVOT and the PIVOT operators.

```
SELECT type, qty
FROM(
     SELECT COALESCE([Type A], 0) AS [Type A],
            COALESCE([Type B], 0) AS [Type B],
            COALESCE([Type C], 0) AS [Type C]
     FROM (
           SELECT [type], [qty]
           FROM #tbl
           ) x
     PIVOT (
            SUM([qty]) FOR [type] IN([Type A], [Type B], [Type C])
            ) p
     )x
UNPIVOT (
         [qty] FOR [type] IN([Type A], [Type B], [Type C])
         ) u
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20c4c/3)